# How can I manage routing in large asp.net mvc projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

What are some strategies for managing the url routing in a large (100+ controllers and growing) MVC project?  Areas has been helpful, but their usefulness seems limited because they can't nest. As the project grows, I've noticed a few big pain points:

1. SEO-friendly routes (every seo route needs a special definition)
2. Redirection for legacy routes (need to 301 old urls to the updated equivalents)
3. Testing routes (is there something better than manual testing and lighter than selenium?)

Also, doesn't performance degrade as the number of routes increases? The way routes are defined suggests performance is at minimum `O(n*k)`, where `n` is the number of defined routes and `k` is the length  at the url.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think this is the case "Areas has been helpful, but their usefulness seems limited" in your situation?

Comment: The reason I ask is that we use portable areas in our solution (using the mvccontrib http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/documentation) and it works well for us.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of questions to consider that may make this easier for you:

- Is there shared functionality between the controllers?
- Is there a way to create a generic pattern for your controller and use some of the events raised by a controller to provide generic functionality (i.e. pulling data from a DB in a consistent pattern)?
- What is fundamentally different between each controller?

The reason for these questions is that I see a couple of potential solutions:

- Assuming you're running on IIS 7 or better, then you could break your functionality into multiple MVC projects for each area. This becomes much easier with IIS 7 and higher (for deployments that is).
- Assuming a consistent pattern of presenting your data, a generic controller or route could make this much easier, allowing you to collapse your controllers.
- A base controller would allow sharing functionality while presenting the specialization you need for each individual controller.

All in all, I would recommend trying to break your code base into multiple MVC projects, based on purpose, to help establish that sense of sanity which seems to be slipping away as your project continues to grow.